# how to make Outlook add-in show up in registry

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, registry, outlook-addin

I have an Outlook Add-in,which is supposed to show a button on appointmentItem Ribbon and on click it performs some task.
I created a installer using Visual Studio Installer (VS 2017 Community Version).
But after installing the setup (.msi file) the Add-in doesn't perform as expected.later I found out that for a Add-in to work in a MS Application it should be present in the regisry.
My Add-n doesn't appear under the registery in Outlook > Add-in dropdown.
Can anyone suggest how to make add-in show up in registry?What changes I have to make while preparing the setup in VS?

Answer (score 0):

The [Registry Entries for VSTO Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx) article describes the required windows registry keys for Office add-ins.

It is not clear what tools you used in Visual Studio for creating an MSI installer. Anyway, you can create a custom action where you can add the required windows registry keys programmatically. Or just configure the installer to add them for you. See the [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx) article for more information.

Comment: Hi, I am using Visual Studio installer. Which s available under         File>New >  Project> Other Project type > visual studio installer > Setup Project